# Paraview and Python on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, vtk, paraview

I've installed the binary distribution of paraview on OSX. When running this I can access the python interpreter from the Tools -> Python Shell. However I cannot figure out which libraries I need to add to PYTHONPATH in order to access VTK and Paraview functionality directly from Python.

Of course I could just compile the source distribution myself, but this would take a lot of time. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok it works when compiling it by hand, but this was not the question..

Answer (score 2):

I am basing my answer on recently built Paraview 3.9.0 from the CVS.  But you should be able to  access ParaView directly from your regular Python if you add:

```
<Paraview-Bld-Directory>/Utilities/VTKPythonWrapping/site-packages
<Paraview-Bld-Directory>/bin
```

to your `PYTHONPATH` variable.

Did this same approach fail to work when you tried the binary distribution?  Sorry, but I wasn't sure how to interpret your comment about it working if you build by hand.

Comment: Yes the question was addressing the binary distribution.. I didn't get it working with the bin distribution, then built it myself and it worked..

Comment: Is there any difference between those directories added to the `PYTHONPATH` in the binary distribution and the build from source?  I have never noticed a difference between the binary distribution and the source build aside from parallel support.